# Parametrizing regions of complex plane

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, geometry

Let $\Omega=\mathbb{C}\setminus \lbrace t e^{it} \ \vert t \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq0} \rbrace$

[image]

I need to write $\Omega= \coprod_{i=0}^{\infty} R_i$ where each $R_i$ is the region bounded by from $t=2k \pi$ to $t=2(k+1) \pi$ and the horizontal axis connecting $2k \pi$ and $2(k+1) \pi$.For example, $R_0$ is the following(without the black strip),

[image]

Similarly we define $R_1$ as the region starting from the black strip in $R_0$ to $t= 4 \pi$ (again with corresponding grey strip not included).

[image]

My question is: How to parametrize such regions $R_i$ so as to talk about them. What is the explicit description of $R_i$.